# System of equations has has no solution if $q > 0$, then what is the value of $q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

System of equations :
**Qx + y + z = Q-1 , x + Qy + z =Q-1 , x + y + Qz = Q-1**

Has no solution if $Q>0$ , then what is the value of $Q$?

I want to solve this using matrices , so I used an **augmented matrix** for these matrices .
I tried converting  them into a **reduced row echelon form matrix** ,but even after a certain amount of operations I’m not able to fully arrive at a matrix where i can successfully apply the **gauss Jordan elimination method**

Comment: Is this $Q\cdot x$ or $Qx$ another variable?

Comment: Just Q .x , as In a linear question in x , y and z with Q as a constant .

Comment: Ah, $Q$ is supposed to be a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gauss algorithm we get
$$x=\frac{Q-1}{Q+2}=y=z$$